# Socket/ZeroMQ – segmentation fault python

Tags: python, сокет, segmentation-fault, zeromq

Цель работы: передача данных из php скрипта в python

Для решения этой задачи я решил использовать socket ( модуль “socket” для python и socket_create для php).

Потом я столкнулся с проблемой, что после 2-3 часов скрипт выдаёт фатальную ошибку “segmentation fault”. Повторюсь, выдаёт не сразу после запуска, а через несколько часов исправной работы.
Код и скриншот ошибки ниже:
[image: Скриншот ошибки socket]

```
def Socket_Server_start():
    socket_finder = socket.socket()
    socket_finder.bind(('', 10999))
    socket_finder.listen(1000)
    while True:
        connect, addr = socket_finder.accept() #Принимаем входящие соединение
        threading.Thread(target=NewConnect, args=(connect, addr,)).start() #Создаём новый поток для работы с сокетом
        del connect, addr
Socket_Server_start() #Запускаем сокет-сервер
```

После неуспеха с socket я решил использовать ZerpMQ
Ситуация осталась точно такой же (после нескольких часов работы скрипт вылетал).
Код и скриншот ошибки ниже:
[image: Скриншот ошибки ZeroMQ]

```
def Socket_Server_start():
    global client, messages
    context = zmq.Context()
    client = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER) #Создаём сервер
    client.bind("tcp://*:5556")
    poll = zmq.Poller()
    poll.register(client, zmq.POLLIN) #Слушаем клиентов
    while True:
        sockets = dict(poll.poll(1000))
        if sockets:
            identity = client.recv().decode() #ID клиента
            msg = client.recv().decode().split("|") #Сообщение от клиента
            #Неважные строчки кода
            if identity not in messages: #Если пользователь с данным ID не подключался
                messages[identity] = [] #Добавляем ID клиента в переменную
                threading.Thread(target=NewConnect, args=(ZeroMQ(identity),)).start() #Запускаем поток для работы с сокетом
            else:
                messages[identity].append(msg) #Клиент уже есть в в переменной -> добавляем сообщение
Socket_Server_start()
```

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы проделали большую работу, пытаясь разобраться. Я могупредположить следующее: оба примера объединяет то, что при соединении или обработке пришедшего сообщения создаётся новый тред. И - вроде бы - он нигде не завершается. Может, треды в пуле кончаются?

Comment: @S.H. Треды завершаются. Это проверял. Хотя думаю стоит перепроверить этот вопрос.

Comment: @S.H. Проверил, потоки завершаются